# dont break line if data ending "\" while writing in csv in php

Tags: php, csv, special-characters

writing in csv file from database, if same id trying to append in "comments" coulmn with same row. but if from database value ending with "\" sign so next comments is writing in new line..if value is not ending with "\" for this working properly.

```html
function cleanComments($string) {
    $cleanstring = trim($string);
    $returnstring = preg_replace("/\n/", "", $cleanstring);
    return $returnstring;
}
function remove_special_char($string) {

    $RemoveChars[] = "([,%+*¢£¥¤¡~©¦§¨ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶¸¹º»¿\[:^print:]])";
    $ReplaceWith = "";
    $text = preg_replace($RemoveChars, $ReplaceWith, $string);

    return $text;
}
```

```html
$comment_text = cleanComments($query_result['user_name'] . ':' . $query_result['comment']);

        if ($counter == 1) {
            $row['comment'].= remove_special_char($comment_text);
        } else {
            $row['comment'].= PHP_EOL . remove_special_char($comment_text);
        }
```

if "\" this special character is ending with dont write in line in csv check my code anyting i missed? or any solution ?

Comment: you can use `substr` to find the pos of `\` in a string, if `\` is the last char, use `continue`

Comment: @while inserting that value its has "Hotel Collection\\\" now getting "Hotel Collection   " with space .. i thing thats why new row writing in new line is it? so whats solution for this

Comment: use `trim($myVar)` to remove the spaces

Comment: i use stripslashes(), trim () but no use

Comment: maybe `str_replace` - but it depends on if slashes are part of normal data, as in, do you want slashes in some fields or are the slashes just there for escaping purposes?

Comment: this issue has been solved by stripslashes();
$comment_text = cleanComments(stripslashes($query_result['user_name'] . ':' . $query_result['comment']));
} 
thank u all.

Answer (score 0):

i changed to this.

```html
    $comment_text = cleanComments(stripslashes($query_result['user_name'] . ':' . $query_result['comment'])); 
        if ($counter == 1) {
            $row['comment'].= remove_special_char($comment_text);
        } else {
            $row['comment'].= PHP_EOL . remove_special_char($comment_text);
        }
```

its working properly now.